# How to open a new window/tab without user interfaction and without getting it blocked

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I've an `<input type="text" />` which shows search suggestions from some data source.

The problem occurs when the user is redirected to some URL and in a new window (i.e. `window.open`) on [ENTER] key press: the Web browser blocks the whole window, because it has been opened without user interaction.

Do you know any way of solving this problem?

What I've tried so far?

- Open a new window by default and change its URL on [ENTER] key press.
- Programatically click the input element.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would I want anyone to be able to spawn new windows without my explicit approval?

Comment: @j08691 These are my project requirements

Comment: Why don't you have a submit button next to the text input? That would solve the problem. Open the new window when the user clicks the submit button.

Comment: @xsearingheaven It's an auto-complete using jQuery and it seems it would be more usable to choose an option using cursors and once you've selected an option just press ENTER.

Comment: if you are in a `form` element and you press *enter*, the whole `form` should be submitted automatically.

Comment: @Ghillied Wow! This worked! Will you post your solution as an answer to my question? I'll mark it as the right one. Thank you!

Comment: @Ghillied That's not consistent across browsers, although a good idea

Comment: @JoanWeeras I posted this as a solution. although Ian is right. Not *all* browsers will trigger the event. Most popular browsers do though (Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera, probably IE9/10 too.)

Comment: @j08691 If you read the question carefully you'll find that the user *does gives explicit approval*. It's not about spawning random windows without user interaction :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

The standard (even though it's **not implemented in every browser**) event when pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>RETURN</kbd> with a `form` element or its children *selected* will be to trigger the `submit` event of it.

---

### Automated Alternative

If you want this event to be called **automatically** you can do it with `JavaScript`:

```
/*Directly selecting the form by its formIndex*/
document.forms[0].submit();

/* --- */    

/* selecting the form by ID */
document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
```

Comment: By the way - since Joan Weeras and me are work colleagues - he understood that the solution wasn't bubbling the keypress of ENTER to the form submit. He tried handling the keypress event on the whole `input` and just calling `document.forms[0].submit()` did the job!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Triggering the event manually is a clever way to do it! Sometimes simple solutions are the hardest to find.

Comment: Will you add the whole solution to your answer? I mean, it's what we require to mark it as the right one! :)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Thank you, the answer has been edited according to your needs :) I added an alternative if the form has an `id` attribute.